# CakePHP Upload Plugin: Programmatic File Retrieval without a Form

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.5

I use [CakePHP-Upload plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload), now need to use the upload without form, following this example: [Programmatic File Retrieval without a Form](http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#programmatic-file-retrieval-without-a-form)

All my upload are stored in the associated model, called the Attachment.
So when I save the article, at the same time save the images in Attachmen model.

**Plugin documentation suggests something like this:**

```
<?php
  $this->Article->set(array('file' => $image_path)); // ?????
  $this->Article->save();
?>
```

I have a larger collection of images on the server, previously uploaded via the Joomla CMS, now I have a migration of data to a custom CMS built on CakePHP framework. **I need to take all these pictures and upload again**, through this plugin.

How to properly use this plugin for my needs, I try to put the path to a local picture, but uploading is not working ???

**EDIT**

```
$image_path = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'attachment' . DS . '59'.DS.'hpim4799.jpg';
debug($image_path);
'C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\webroot\img\attachment\59\hpim4799.jpg'
```

Do not save the record and not create new images.
Note, uploading through HTML form works well, I use windows 7 and xampp server.

**EDIT 2 / Solution**

Image path **must be valid url** like 'http://localhost/portal/img/attachment/59/hpim4799.jpg'

```
 $image_path = Router::url('/', true) . 'img/attachment/59/hpim4799.jpg';
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are saying that you need to upload all images again. Why? The upload-plugin stores uploads in a table. If you can find out what path it is, and what name, you can build some code to generate the database-rows, and copy the files manual?

Comment: No, I need to generate new thumbnails in different size from the original image that is already on the server. I have saved the file names in the database, the original images are located in one folder. The plan is to make a loop of all the record, find related images and generate new images that will be placed in folders by id number of records.

Comment: Ah okay... I will check its documentation, but can't promise I've the answer ;)

Comment: Does the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\webroot\img\attachment\59\hpim4799.jpg` really exists. If the upload isn't working it should not exist?

Comment: Yes, there is a file. Yes, there is a file. Behavior only work with remote files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching for solutions and detailed inspection of the Behavior code I finally found it.

Because Behavior uses php **FILTER_VALIDATE_URL** Filter, path must be a valid URL. Here is an example:

```
<?php
  $image_path = Router::url('/', true) . 'img/attachment/59/hpim4799.jpg';
  // return http://localhost/portal/img/attachment/59/hpim4799.jpg

  $this->Article->Attachment->set(array('file' => $image_path)); 
  $this->Article->Attachment->save();
?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what this piece of code actually do? I did not found any explanation in the documentation. Can i pass any valid image-url as $image_path? for example a google image .jpg-link? Or has the image data to be located on the same server local?

Comment: Simple upload any remote file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what the content of the variable `$image_url` is? The doucmentation says you can add a file via the form, or you can do it programmatically. If you do that, use the `$image_url` as path to the image. If you got an associated model like `Attachment` you shoud use:

```
<?php
  $this->Article->set(array('Attachment.file' => $image_path)); // path + file to file
  $this->Article->save();
?>
```

Comment: Before I put the question, I tried it that way. It seems to me that the plugin has a bug.

Comment: I doubt that... Are you sure that the variable `$image_url` is right?

Comment: Can you debug the `$image_url`, your programatically code, and the loading of the behavior (`$actsas`)?